# React Page won't load unless refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a dynamic route from my app.js.
I have 2 pages. HomePage.js and ReportPageLayout.js.

When I try to navigate from HomePage to ReportPage, I am getting a status= cancelled.
[Image of Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyK8N.png)

When i refresh the page in the browser, the data is fetched and rendered.[Image status=200 and component rendered on dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLKX9.png)

Here is my app.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import ReportPage from './pages/ReportPageLayout';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
                    <Route path="/:id" component={ReportPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of react are you using?

Comment: @dpthegrey I'm using react version 18.0.0

Comment: I don't see any issue with this code specifically. How are you running your app?

Comment: Oh, there's currently a compatibility issue between `react@18` and `react-router-dom@5`. https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870 might have some relevant information for you, though it hasn't updated since I last checked it.

Comment: @DrewReese I use npm start

Comment: @Drew Reese Ohh okay!. If i install react-router-dom@6, will it fix the issue? I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833424/8690857 may help as well.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put the ReportPage route before the Homepage route?

Comment: @Woodchuck I'll check it.

Comment: Which version of router do you use?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks. I think that the issue is with react v18.

Comment: have you tried using element instead of component? `<Route path="/:id" element={ReportPage} />`

Comment: @ZurielS.G. v5.3

Comment: @dpthegrey Yes. Geting the same result.

Comment: @Woodchuck It's not working if I interchange their positions.

Answer (score 1):

for me, the following updation worked,

If you use are using React Router 5.3.x, check whether it is 5.3.3 in your package.json file.

If it is not 5.3.3 uninstall the last version then install the bug-free version which has been resolved by John and updated in version 5.3.3.

> npm uninstall -S react-router-dom 
> npm install -S react-router-dom@5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (not that much), in router-dom v5 you should nest the target component and not as an argument

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import ReportPage from './pages/ReportPageLayout';

export default function App() {
   return (
      <Fragment>
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Homepage/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/:id">
                <ReportPage/>
            </Route>
         </Switch>
      </Fragment>
   );
}
```

Furthermore, if you use suspense or importing data from, you should always create a fallback.
I had the same thing here
[Delay in loading the array crushs the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547563/delay-in-loading-the-array-crushs-the-app)

Comment: No, RRDv5 has several [rendering methods]. There exists a `component` and `render` and `children` function props, as well as just implicitly rendering `children` components like your answer.